# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) on adding the line const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-hooks, react-redux

I'm trying to create google clone and getting undefined is not iterable error when I added
`const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();` and I'm using Context API.

Search.js:

```
import { useStateValue } from "./StateProvider";
import { actionTypes } from './reducer';


function Search({ hideButtons = false })
{
    const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();

    const [input, setInput] = useState('')
    const history = useNavigate(); //provides browser history

    const search = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault(); //not to refresh

        console.log('you hit search', input);

        dispatch({
            type: actionTypes.SET_SEARCH_TERM,
            term: input
        })

        history('/search'); //on search button click, it will push us to search page
    }
}
```

StateProvider.js

```
import React, { createContext, useContext, useReducer } from "react";

export const StateContext = createContext();

export const StateProvider = ({ reducer, initialState, childern }) => (
    <StateContext.Provider value=
    {useReducer(reducer, initialState)}>
        {/* app component */}
        {childern} 
    </StateContext.Provider>
);

export const useStateValue = () => useContext(StateContext);
```

I basically have home page and search page and I'm trying to get the data which is entered in the search bar(in home page) to the search page using the context API.

Comment: You misspelled `children`.

Comment: Thanks, but the error still stays the same.
Error: Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator)) at the line const [{}, dispatch] = useStateValue();